# get url parameter in php with $GET

Tags: php, html, parameters, get

I am passing a parameter in my URL address which I want to use in my PHP to build a directory path which will then be used by the PHP as image directory to build HTML

My URL is:-
http://www.icrrc.x10host.com/Pages/gallery-test1.php?galleryName=General

My PHP is:

```
$gallery = 'Images/Gallery/'$_GET['galleryName'];
```

I then use `$gallery` to build the `img src=image` filenames in my HTML

My problem is with the `$_GET`, I am being returned:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_GET' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/icrrcx10/public_html/Pages/gallery-test1.php on line 111
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with my syntax as I am a newbie to php?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your syntax, corrected and shown below

```
$gallery = "Images/Gallery/".$_GET['galleryName'];
```

Comment: Thanks Unni Babu I thought it would be something easy

Comment: @alan... if this helps :) dont forget to select this as answer...always welcome